# Multiple JSESSIONID Cookies depending on login path

Tags: jsf, servlets, cookies, tomcat7, jsessionid

I have a tomcat 7.0 application with declarative security (on the context root path) in localhost. The login is performed on a jsf action calling httpServletRequest#login method

It works fine if the initial request is /somepage.xhtml, the login page is displayed, the user posts the login data and I do a call to HttpServletRequest.login to login. Then the cookie has correct path and it works fine

The problem comes when the initial request is /somefolder/somepage.xhtml. The JSESSIONID cookie is in path /contextRoot/somefolder. When I submit the login and after the login I can see that I have 2 JSESSIONID cookies (one with path / and another one with /somefolder/ path). It works fine navigating in the root folder but when I hit a /somefolder page the session is missed.

In my context.xml I have

```
<Context  sessionCookiePath="/"
```

although it does not seem to work (and this is not exactly what I want...)

Any ideas? Thx in advance

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Tomcat. Which Tomcat version exactly are you using? Tried the latest if any available?

Comment: I'm using TomEE 1.7.0, which is using tomcat 7.0.55. I'm also using deltaspike but it should not be relevant in this context.

Comment: Do you think that the bug is having multiple cookies in different paths?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

It happens with the JVM switch

```
 -Dorg.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true
```

(I was also testing session serialization to disk). If I remove this switch only one JSESSIONID is created.